# I want my browser to run a javascipt file on every opened tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I wrote some code to a javascript file and **I was wondering if it's possible to make my browser run that file on every tab in the browser(basically run the js file every time a tab is opened).** If not are there alternatives to achieve the same effect?

Comment: You could simply use an extension such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/codeinjector/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.